# pdf loader for nuxt.js

Tags: pdf, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to add the correct pdf loader to my nuxt.config.js file but nothing seems to be working so far. This is what I have in my build config, I'm pretty sure I need to add another rule to get pdf working but is not happening.

```
extend(config, ctx) {
  // Run ESLint on save
  if (ctx.isDev && ctx.isClient) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      enforce: "pre",
      test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
      loader: "eslint-loader",
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    });
  }
},
```

},

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my downloadable pdf files and solved it by moving the download's folder to the static directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to archive this by extending the build config in the `nuxt.config.js`.

```js
module.exports = {
  build: {
    extend(config) {
      // Find the rule which contains a assets file extension
      const assetsLoader = config.module.rules.find(rule => rule.test.test('.png'));

      // Overwrite the test regex and add `pdf`
      assetsLoader.test = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|pdf)$/i;

      return config;
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to resolve it is by **loading the instance of jspdf in the client-side**.

```
if(process.client) {
  const jsPDF = require('jspdf');
  require('jspdf-autotable');

  let doc = new jsPDF();
  // ...your code
}
```

As per the Nuxt Documentation, check this out [Window Document Undefined](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/window-document-undefined/).